# Как проверить в объекте JSON наличие определенного поля

Tags: javascript, json

Есть поле в ответе

```
Status: ok
```

Как проверить на его присутствие в респонсе

Пробовал такой код (не работает):

```
var json = '{"status"}',
    data = JSON.parse(responseBody);

if ('status' in data) {
    alert('Status: ok');
} else {
    alert('поля нет');
}
```

Comment: У вас невалидный JSON: `{"status"}` (объект должен содержать пары ключ-значение). Потому и не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(data.status !== undefined){
 alert("Status:"+data.status);
}
```

Но по хорошему поле статус (если его название в вашем коде соотвествует логике работы) должно быть всегда (просто принимать значение false к примеру), так  код будет более логичным.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!